# kernel works but shouldn't

Tags: c++, cuda

I run kernel with one thread per block like this `<<<NUMBER_OF_BLOCKS, 1>>>`.

On my GPU (according to `deviceQuery`) I can run only 512 blocks. So it should work only if `NUMBER_OF_BLOCKS` <= 512 but program still works if I run 32768 blocks. Bad results show when I run 65536 blocks  and more.

What did I miss?

Comment: Unlike you were not jedis, so we cant read minds. Were going to need your code to help you.

Answer (score 2):

> What did I miss?

Nowhere does it say your GPU can only run 512 blocks. It says your GPU can only run 512 *threads per block* viz:

```
 CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)

There is 1 device supporting CUDA

Device 0: "GeForce 320M"
  CUDA Driver Version:                           5.0
  CUDA Runtime Version:                          5.0
  CUDA Capability Major/Minor version number:    1.2
  Total amount of global memory:                 265027584 bytes
  Multiprocessors x Cores/MP = Cores:            1 (MP) x 8 (Cores/MP) = 8 (Cores)
  Total amount of constant memory:               65536 bytes
  Total amount of shared memory per block:       16384 bytes
  Total number of registers available per block: 16384
  Warp size:                                     32
  Maximum number of threads per block:           512
  Maximum sizes of each dimension of a block:    512 x 512 x 64
  Maximum sizes of each dimension of a grid:     65535 x 65535 x 1
  Maximum memory pitch:                          2147483647 bytes
  Texture alignment:                             256 bytes
  Clock rate:                                    0.95 GHz
  Concurrent copy and execution:                 Yes
  Run time limit on kernels:                     Yes
  Integrated:                                    Yes
  Support host page-locked memory mapping:       Yes
  Compute mode:                                  Exclusive (only one host thread at a time can use this device)
  Concurrent kernel execution:                   Yes
  Device has ECC support enabled:                No
  Device is using TCC driver mode:               Yes

deviceQuery, CUDA Driver = CUDART, CUDA Driver Version = 5.0, CUDA Runtime Version = 5.0, NumDevs = 1, Device = GeForce 320M
```

All CUDA capable GPUs can run grids of up to 65535 x 65535 blocks per kernel launch. Newer devices can run larger grids than that.

Comment: @MrJedi: in that example blocksNum can legally be any number up to 65535. threadsNum can only be up to 512....

Comment: Ok, but I use only one dimension of block which is 512. If i run smth like this: 

 int threadsNum = 1;
 int blocksNum = 1024;
 writeCubeInBinaryForm<<<blocksNum,threadsNum>>>(d_cubeData,n,twoPowerN,arraySize);

 
It should't work because is overloaded, right?

Comment: Formating don't work... 

@talonmies but is grid dimension, no blocks dimension...